Mouse Listener in python
I have an error and I will share with you on the below.
The code I wrote is so simple. I didnt understand why I get this error.
Code:
import timeimport threading
from pynput.mouse import Listener

def clicker(x,y,button,pressed):print("a")
with Listener(on_click=clicker) as listener:listener.join()

Error:
Unhandled exception in listener callback
Traceback (most recent call last):File "C:\Users\Arda\PycharmProjects\pythonProject.venv\Lib\site-packages\pynput_util\win32.py", line 386, in _handlerconverted = self._convert(code, msg, lpdata)File "C:\Users\Arda\PycharmProjects\pythonProject.venv\Lib\site-packages\pynput_util\win32.py", line 401, in _convertraise NotImplementedError()NotImplementedError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):File
"C:\Users\Arda\PycharmProjects\pythonProject.venv\Lib\site-packages\pynput_util_init_.py",
line 229, in innerreturn f(self, *args, **kwargs)File
"C:\Users\Arda\PycharmProjects\pythonProject.venv\Lib\site-packages\pynput_util\win32.py",
line 390, in _handlerself._handle(code, msg, lpdata)~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^TypeError:
'_thread._ThreadHandle' object is not callable

I want to print do-something when I clicked left-mouse

It looks like the problem is with your installation. Please [edit] your question to include your operating system, python and pynput versions. While you're at it, fix the code formatting.

well i dont know how you got that error because, you already have error in first line, not sure if you are trying to import two modules. format it. as suggested by @importrandom reinstall the package because its working fine on linux(ubuntu 24.04)

@BishnuChalise if I fix the obvious indentation and line end errors in the code. it runs for me on Windows 11 with pynput 1.7.7.
